# Making a certain Element of an array interactable using a PlayerPrefs float while all of the +1 elements remain locked

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, 3d

So basically I have a Score/Highscore system and I also have an array which contains some of the buttons which change the color of the player's character. So my question is that if I have highscoreCount >= 20, I want a certain button to become interactable.

ScoreManager Script

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public Text scoreText;
    public Text highScoreText;

    public float scoreCount;
    public float highscoreCount;

    public float pointsPerSecond;

    public bool scoreIncreasing;

    public Button[] CustomizeButtons;


    void Start()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Highscore"))
        {
            highscoreCount = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Highscore");
        }

        int CustomizationButtonReached = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CustomizationButtonReached", 1);
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < CustomizeButtons.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i + 1 > CustomizationButtonReached)
                    CustomizeButtons[i].interactable = false;
            }
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {

        if (scoreIncreasing)
        {
            scoreCount += pointsPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if(scoreCount > highscoreCount)
        {
            highscoreCount = scoreCount;
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Highscore", highscoreCount);
        }

        scoreText.text = "Score: " + Mathf.Round(scoreCount);
        highScoreText.text = "Highscore: " + Mathf.Round(highscoreCount);
    }
}
```

CustomizeColors Script

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CustomizeColors : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Color[] Colors;
    public Material Mat;


    public void Start()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("HeadColor"))
        {
            Mat.color = Colors[PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HeadColor")];
        }
    }

    public void ChangeColor(int colorIndex)
    {
        Mat.color = Colors[colorIndex];
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HeadColor", colorIndex);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
}
```

Essentially this is the code that I have made (in the ScoreManager) to make an array and to disable all of the buttons. I just want to get a specific element to be interactable when highscoreCount >= "number"

```
    public Button[] CustomizeButtons;


    void Start()
    {
        int CustomizationButtonReached = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CustomizationButtonReached", 1);
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < CustomizeButtons.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i + 1 > CustomizationButtonReached)
                    CustomizeButtons[i].interactable = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go multiple ways about this, for example storing a reference for that specific button and when the condition you mentioned is true just set that one button to be interactable

```
[SerializeField] Button button; //Set this in the inspector

public void AddToScore(int score)
{
   //Do your score adding stuff

   if (highscoreCount >= number)
   {
      button.interactable = true
   }
}
```